# Null check for all class members in effective way

Tags: c#, wcf

Working in WCF service. I have class called Customer with 10 fields. I want to ensure at least one should have value.

Unfortunately the class is not null but all the class members are null from the input request

Is there any simple and effect way to check to confirm at least one class field has value rather checking `field1.IsnotNullOrEmpty() & field2.IsnotnullOrEmpty()......field10.IsnotNullOrEmpty()`

Comment: Is there a way to check whether all of the fields are empty without checking if all of the fields are empty?  No.

Comment: That is the most effective way, unless you switch to using a backing dictionary or something. You could use reflection to iterate over fields, but your way is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: What are your criteria for "effective" and "simple"?  Memory usage, speed, readability, maintainability? And btw: this sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe an instance method like `Customer.HasAtLeastOneValue()` is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Well you can't put **[Required]** on everything so perhaps implement **IValidatableObject.Validate**

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all properties like this (just short sample of code)

```
bool HasValue<T>(T obj)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    return type.GetProperties().Where(p =>
    {
        var val = p.GetValue(obj);
        if (val is string) return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val as string);
        return val != null;
    }).Any();
}
```

But as was said, your way is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: That iterates properties, not fields.  You can also eliminate the `Where`, just replace it with `Any`

Comment: No problem, it's an easy slip.

Comment: Thank you folks!! I was looking for this type of solution. But, as you mentioned i just go by checking nullOrEmpty() as i just have 3 fields verify, actually.